# Set Selected Value on Dropdown Based on Model Property

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a simple dropdown like :

```
<%= collection_select("user_cities", "city_id", current_user.cities, :id, :name ) %>
```

current_user.cities is an array of the user cities. Each city has a field named "is_primary" and only one city has it set as true.

My question is, how can i make the above collection_select(or transform it if needed), so that it picks the selected option, based on City.is_primary ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select):

> By default, `post.person_id` *[in your case `user_cities.city_id`]* is the selected option. Specify `:selected => value` to use a different selection or `:selected => nil` to leave all options unselected.

Armed with that knowledge we can pass the appropriate option to `collection_select`:

```
<%= collection_select "user_cities", "city_id", current_user.cities, :id, :name,
      :selected => current_user.cities.detect(&:is_primary).id
%>
```

Comment: yes i've seen that, but that is not what i am asking. Please read my question again.

Answer (score 1):

```
collection_select("user_cities", "city_id", current_user.cities, :id, :name,{:selected => current_user.cities.where(:is_primary => 1)})
```

Comment: seems nice, but it does not work :/ (probably needs a '.id' in the end i guess)

Answer (score 1):

I would start by defining a method called primary_city in your User model.

```
def primary_city
  cities.where(:is_primary => true).first
end
```

Then,

```
<%= collection_select("user_cities", "city_id", current_user.cities, :id, :name, { :selected=> current_user.primary_city.id } ) %>
```

Comment: yeap, that is what i was actually doing now :) +1 (though probably removing .first, i prefer to leave relations there till i really need an object)